# Saving Canvas with the background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas element with a background image. User is allowed to draw on the image and then need to save the complete canvas element with the background. I'm using below code for saving part but it only gets the canvas drawing but not the background image. what could i do to get the background image also?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('your_canvas');
             var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
             // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
             var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

             // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
             // so it can be saved as an image
             document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

Update:

My HTML

```
<div name='coords1' class='canvas-area input-xxlarge' disabled
placeholder='Shape Coordinates' id='imgDiv'
data-image-url='BackGround.jpg'></div>
```

I have the above div in my HTML page. then i dynamically create the canvas and draw on it. It's a bit lengthy code.

Comment: you need to bring the background image inside the `<canvas>` and then you can get canvas drawing as well as bkg image.

Comment: Are you drawing the background image on canvas before allowing the user to draw on the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use image on the `div`, draw the image on the `canvas` ..

use the following code to draw image on canvas,

```
var img=new Image();
img.src=/*image src*/;
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
img.onload=function()
{
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);
}
```

After image drawing completion at `img.onload` callback , allow user to draw on canvas...

Now save the canvas drawing....

Answer (score 0):

**To Get the Canvas with backgound Image**

```
context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
drawImage(yourBackgroundImage,0,0);
```